Android Virtual Device is stuck in task bar?
I was using AVD to build flutter applications with VS code. I don't know why but the AVD started to run only in task bar, when i hover it i can see it works. Then i went to Android Studio and started the AVD and it started properly in running devices window. The main problem is i cannot start AVD as a separated application. It only run in minimized mode. It only happens with high resolution virtual devices. Do you know why this happens?

More details about what is going on in the logcat might be helpful in addition to what your PC setup is (CPU (Intel/AMD model number),RAM size, GPU, free hard drive storage,etc. AVDs do take up a lot of resources which increases with device display size. You should also check how you are handling https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration
